# spTransform produces unexpected results

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sp, rgdal

I am struggling to plot points using WGS84 co-ordinates on a map of the UK using the OSGB 1936 / British National Grid CRS. I'm using the rgdal package in R.

Here is my reproducible example, using the co-ordinates of Buckingham Palace...

```
library(rgdal)
foo <- data.frame(lat = 51.500829, long = -0.142994)
bar <- SpatialPoints(foo)
proj4string(bar) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
bar <- spTransform(bar, CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))
coordinates(bar)
```

This outputs the following transformed co-ordinates:

```
         lat     long
[1,] 7464126 -5554500
```

Where I should be getting latitude of 179622 and longitude of 528993.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? The only similar problem I could find was [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271120/why-did-sptransform-fail-here?newreg=5c7259830f8d4a75b8fd2719e003f043) and I'm now pretty confident I am choosing the right CRSs. I'm trying to do something similar to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64654/choosing-the-correct-value-for-proj4string-for-shapefile-reading-in-r) but again, I don't think the solutions there can help me.

P.S. I'm using [this site](https://epsg.io/map#srs=4326&x=-0.142994&y=51.500822&z=17&layer=streets) to check what co-ordinates I should be getting.

Comment: technically they are eastings and northings after the transform not lat/lon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: ***x* is longitude and *y* is latitude.** (For geographic coordinates. East and north for projected coordinates)

Solution:

```
library(rgdal)
foo <- data.frame(y = 51.500829, x = -0.142994) # lat == y, long == x
coordinates(foo) <- ~x+y
proj4string(foo) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
bar <- spTransform(foo, CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))
coordinates(bar)
##          x        y
## 1 528992.9 179622.5
```

Comment: The core problem is that `SpatialPoints(foo)` ignores the names on the data frame and takes the first column as the "X" coordinate (longitude) and the second column as "Y" (latitude).

Comment: @Spacedman yes, indeed [isn't explicit](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.2-7/topics/SpatialPoints) the order of input coordinates